# :hover#id on all web browser & devices - should work?

Tags: css

Normally we write this way:

```css
#id span:hover {}
```

I tried this and it worked.

```css
:hover#id span {}
```

Will this work in all web browsers and devices ?

Comment: will work instead in touch based mobiles :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Till this date I have used this in many browser, It works perfectly for me in every browser,

```
HTML
<div id="id">
     <span>hello</span>
     <br>
     <a href="">hover me</a> 
  </div>
```

Css

```
  #id span:hover{
   color: red;
  }
```

In this if you Hover on hello only hello will change the color

Now if you write CSS like

```
:hover#id span{
  color: red;
}
```

In this, where ever you hover inside #id, whole block will trigger, not only that particular span.